# How to validate numericality and inclusion while still allowing attribute to be nil in some cases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails app I have several integer attributes on a model.

A user should be able to create a record and leave these attributes blank.

Or, if the user enters values for these attributes, they should be validated for numericality and within a certain range.

In the model I have something like this

```
validates_presence_of :name    
validates_numericality_of :a, :only_integer => true, :message => "can only be whole number."
validates_inclusion_of :a, :in => 1..999, :message => "can only be between 1 and 999."
```

If I now test with the minimum required attributes to save:

```
factory :model do
  sequence(:name) { |n| "model#{n}" }
end

it "should save with minium attributes" do
  @model = FactoryGirl.build(:model)
  @model.save.should == false
end
```

I get

```
Validation failed: a can only be whole number., a can only be between 1 and 999.
```

How can I validate numericality and inclusion only if a value is given for `:a`, while still allowing `:a` to be nil in some cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can add an `:allow_nil => true` to your `validates_numericality_of`.

```
validates_numericality_of :a, :only_integer => true, :allow_nil => true, 
    :message => "can only be whole number."
```

You can also use `greater_than_or_equal_to` and `less_than_or_equal_to` options if you just want to use one validation:

```
validates_numericality_of :a, :only_integer => true, :allow_nil => true, 
    :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1,
    :less_than_or_equal_to => 999,
    :message => "can only be whole number between 1 and 999."
```

Answer (score 3):

should be simply:

```
validates_numericality_of :a, :only_integer => true, :message => "can only be whole number.", :allow_nil => true
```

same for the second validation

Comment: thanks, this was just what I needed. I've given the answer to Shadwell for his DRY code. Shame I can't mark both as correct.